# Azure Function App Http Redirect

Tags: azure, azure-functions, http-redirect

I have a function app which works as expected for http**s**.

Someone in my organisation created a link to it, but forgot the "s" in https... the result is a redirect (supplied by the function app) to https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.net/ms-ext-routing/v1   (the "ms-ext-routing" portion is added by the function app, it seems - the "v1" is part of the original url)

This yields a 404.

I've tried creating a separate function to intercept this unknown url and redirect back to the https version of the app, with no success.

**So, what is this redirect and how can I fix it / compensate?**  (other than the obvious option of getting people to link to the correct protocol - which is in process as I write this)

Comment: It sounds that fixing the link is a far better option than doing redirects. Try to contact the person who can change the link.

Comment: I agree @Peter - but for future Function App users, including myself, it would be useful to be able to handle such a scenario gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

The function app should have Azure Functions Proxies enabled and a route defined as /v1. Look for the proxies.json file in the root of your function app.

If proxies are not needed you can disable them in the portal.

Comment: v1 is a function already (and there is no /api prefix for the app).  Sorry, this doesn't solve the problem.  Thanks though :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion of a proxy (instead of a function with a redirect) and the result is the same:  proxy from [http]://my-app.azurewebsites.net/ms-ext-routing to [https]://my-app.azurewebsites.net  yields a redirect to [https]://my-app.azurewebsites.net/ms-ext-routing/ms-ext-routing[/whatever-I-put-here] for any request.   (Protocol segments put in square brackets because a) they matter and b) stack overflow was converting them to links)

Comment: Did you verify your existing function app does not have Proxies enabled? that's the only way you would get /ms-ext-routing/ in the redirects.

Comment: It does have proxies enabled (It had one already in operation). What's happening, is I get that path (/ms-ext-routing/) appended when the original request isn't over TLS.

Comment: Ok If proxies are enabled, would you mind sharing the proxies.json file? It is located in the root of the function app.

Comment: {
    "proxies": {
        "_storage_static_proxy": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/content/{*filename}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "[https]://my-storage-account-name.blob.core.windows.net/public/{filename}"
        }
    }
}

Comment: (That's the existing, working proxy - protocol of backendUri wrapped in squary brackets to prevent SO from converting it to a hyperlink)

Comment: (sorry for the delayed reply: weekend.)  :-)

Comment: You should be able to replicate this yourself:  set up is as follows: a function app with Azure active directory authentication  (anonymous requests allowed).  Modify the host.json as follows: {
        "http": {
        routePrefix: ""
    }
}     Next, create a function which checks if the current user request is authenticated (via turn-key Azure App Service).    The result: a https request to that function works.  A http request results in a redirect to /ms-ext-routing/[your-function].

Comment: Login check looks roughly like this in C#:      var user = "Anonymous";
    var claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    if (claimsPrincipal != null && claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        user = claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    }         
   else
    {
        // Redirecting
        var res = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        res.Headers.Location = new Uri(req.RequestUri, $"/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_uri={req.RequestUri.AbsolutePath}&token_mode=session");
        return res;
    }

Comment: Great, Thanks! I can repro the issue. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We have verified this is a bug on our side and will release a fix for this issue.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Henry - update your answer when it's released and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Hi Henry, any idea when this patch will be released?

Comment: The patch should be released globally by end of April as part of the next roll out of App Service release.. Thanks!